# How to verify if a dll is a COM component or a normal dll

Tags: windows, com

Are there any ways to identify if a dll is a COM component or not ,by going through the code

Comment: It might help if you told us why you think you need to know this. What are you going to do differently if it is a COM DLL?

Answer (score 2):

COM DLL exports [`DllGetClassObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which you can locate via `GetProcAddress` API. There might be other (not just optional, they typically are exported), but this one is a must to exist.

Also for the record, COM DLLs are also normal, they are not abnormal.

Comment: What do you mean by normal and abnormal?